# Did Trump muse on the different names for the UK?

Tags: quotes, donald-trump

According to an article in *The Guardian*, the occasion of his visit to the United Kingdom elicited a philosophical thought about its many possible names.

> “We would make a great deal with the United Kingdom because they have product that we like,” Trump said. “I mean they have a lot of great product. They make phenomenal things, you know, **and you have different names – you can say ‘England’, you can say ‘UK’, you can say ‘United Kingdom’** … the fact is you make great product, you make great things. Even your farm product is so fantastic.”
>
> <sub>Donald Trump, [as quoted by *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/jul/15/trump-reveals-the-queens-private-views-on-brexit) *(emphasis mine)*</sub>

The first time I read it, it came across as a parody of something Trump might say.

Is this an actual quote by Donald Trump? Is there a transcript available?

Comment: I closed this as off-topic because the Guardian clearly gives the source. The source is a first-person account *and* the interview will be shortly published as a video on ITV. Any answer before then will basically be a rehash on the single source. Any answer after then will be simply a link to the video.

Comment: @Oddthinking fair enough.